# Entity adapter getSelectors method generates "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, ngrx-entity

I am trying to use `createEntityAdapter` from `reduxjs/toolkit` to generate selectors automatically.

I have created a "select all" selector successfully using `create selector`:

```js
export const selectEnvironmentsResult = extendedApiSlice.endpoints.getEnvironments.select()

export const selectAllEnvironments = createSelector(
  selectEnvironmentsResult,
  environmentsResult => environmentsResult?.data ?? []
)
```

And works fine:

```js
const data = useSelector(selectAllEnvironments) // data is correctly defined :)
```

But, when I try to use `createEntityAdapter` to create the selectors:

```js
export const selectEnvironmentsResult = extendedApiSlice.endpoints.getEnvironments.select()

export const selectAllEnvironments = createSelector(
  selectEnvironmentsResult,
  environmentsResult => environmentsResult?.data ?? []
)


export const {
  selectAll,
  selectById,
  selectIds,
} = environmentsAdapter.getSelectors((state) => {
    const selected = selectAllEnvironments(state) ?? initialState
    console.log( selected ) // prints "[]"
    return selected
  }
)
```

and use it, I get an error:

```js
const data = useSelector(selectAll) // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the `transformReponse` value. You should use the `adapter.setAll` function:

```
      transformResponse: (responseData) => {
        return adapter.setAll(adapter.getInitialState(), responseData)
      },
```